# ReWrite condition for a direct hit on the root domain

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for a .htaccess `ReWrite` condition that works on a direct hit on the root domain of a website. It should load the url if the user entered or copied the url in the address bar as opposed to navigating from a referrer.

It should fail in all these cases:

`https://www.example.com/subdir`

`https://www.example.com?param`

directed to `https://www.example.com` from another domain.

It should work only in this case:

User entered or copied `https://www.example.com` , `www.example.com` or `example.com` into the address bar.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I was looking for

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/*/.
```